# What is the first on-screen use of R2-D2's "taser"?

Tags: star-wars, r2-d2

I can't recall R2 using it in *A New Hope*, and I know he shocks an Ewok in *Return of the Jedi*, but I can't recall the first time audiences see that R2-D2 has this ability.

**When was the first time audiences saw that R2-D2 could 'electrocute'?**

Comment: are you asking in-universe or in real-life?

Comment: @NKCampbell Yeah, in real-life, R2-D2 electrocuted President Nixon the day before he resigned.

Comment: The first time in real-life that audiences saw it on-screen. Like, when people then could say "Oh, R2-D2 can do ___".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of release date, Artoo first uses his "shock prod" to break Leia's bonds in Return of the Jedi.

[image]

Shortly afterwards he uses the same appendage to shock Salacious Crumb.

[image]

Much later in the film he zaps the ewok Logray several times.

[image]

In terms of in-universe chronology, the first time we see Artoo using an electro-prod is in Star Wars: The Clone Wars and then again in Revenge of the Sith. Note that it originally projected from the top of his chassis, not from a panel in the front. It's possible that it was moved by Luke to make space for his hidden lightsaber ejector.

[image][image]

---

Interestingly, in the [novelisation for Return of the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel)), the order of events is rather different. R2-D2 cuts Leia's chains with a "*cutting appendage*" and the very first thing to get shocked with his prod was [Hermi Odle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hermi_Odle) rather than Salacious Crumb.

> *He zipped up to her finally, extended a cutting appendage from the side of his casing, and sliced through her bonds.
>   “Thanks, Artoo, good work. Now let’s get out of here.”
>
>   They raced for the door. On the way, they passed Threepio, lying on the floor, screaming, as a giant, tuberous hulk named Hermi Odle sat on him. Salacious Crumb, the reptilian monkey-monster, crouched by Threepio’s head, picking out the golden droid’s right eye.
>
>   “No! No! Not my eyes!” Threepio screamed.
>
>   **Artoo sent a bolt of charge into Hermi Odle’s backside**, sending him wailing through a window. A similar flash blasted Salacious to the ceiling, from which he didn’t come down. Threepio quickly rose, his eye dangling from a sheaf of wires; then he and Artoo hurriedly followed Leia out the back door.*

Comment: TimSparrow mentioned a scene where Artoo uses it to weld in ESB. Is that something you know of? If so, I'd probably count it as a 'first use', even if it wasn't used on a creature (since it would be the same appendage, presumably). Edit: Nvm, I read the new comments on that answer, and it's a different tool.

Comment: @TVann - You don't see the appendage. He's buried elbow-deep in the panel and he's not welding, he's fixing something

Answer (score 3):

**You are correct**

R2-D2 uses electric discharge for welding, as seen in "*The Empire Strikes Back"*, when Millenium Falcon is damaged by the enemy fire. First time he used this ability to shock beings was in **Return Of The Jedi**.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific on the scene in ESB? I'm having trouble remembering when R2 is welding with his 'electrocute arm'.

Comment: In ESB: he is shown to be welding C-3PO's foot but it's a different tool: http://i.imgur.com/kzrVM9D.jpg  - you may be misremembering Chewie's electrical tool in the same scene: http://i.imgur.com/wbtMefb.png

Comment: this is the tool R2 uses to repair the Falcon, and it's different from the shock prod: http://i.imgur.com/XxAkvhR.png

Comment: also - in ESB, the Falcon isn't damaged by enemy fire, but it was disabled on Vader's orders :)